# Optimizing a mono-CPU application in a docker environment (multi-core vs multi-instances)

Tags: performance, docker, multi-core, multiple-instances, load-balancer

I have a simple, CPU-bound, mono-CPU application running in a docker container.
Indeed it fully uses a single CPU on the instance when processing work.

As I understand, there are two main approaches to improve the performance of the application:

- rewrite the application so that it runs natively on multiple CPU
- run the application as many times as there are CPUs behind a loadbalancer (each instance would process a chunk of the workload)

What are the pros and cons of these approaches?
How to select to the ideal one?
Are there others?

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but it doesn't fit here. It needs a forum, where open ended discussion is the norm. Here we need specific, usually practical, questions that can have a single specific answer.

Comment: Indeed this is a wide question, but there may be good practices out there for this type of problem. Do you recommend any forum? Are there such forums in SO?